# Change size of alertViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I want to add switches and labels to my alertViewController, so i need to change the size of the alertViewController.
How can I do this (Objective C).
Thanks

Comment: `UIAlertController` doesn't support such customizations.

Answer (score 2):

Somebody posted an answer and then deleted it. As rmaddy says in his comments, you can't customize `UIAlertController` like that. You'll have to create your own custom alert controller class, or find a third party framework that offers the features that you want.

(When I've needed to customize an alert beyond what Apple's `UIAlertController` allows, I had good luck finding a 3rd party library that let me do what I needed to do.)

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the size of the alert view controller. Make a custom view and add on it.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to create a subclass of `UIAlertController` thats the only way you can modify something.

I recommend that you use a third party library [SCLAlertView](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SCLAlertView)

Comment: No, don't subclass `UIAlertController`. Please read the documentation for `UIAlertController` where it states that it is not for subclassing.